# How to model multi-response data with subjects across multiple experiments?

Tags: multiple-regression, multivariate-analysis, psychology

We have shown people different images and asked them to give a text response. They had unlimited time to provide their response.

We have 14 different images, and each person only saw each image once. Each person saw all 14 images in the same session. Additionally, we varied the time that each image was displayed. We had 7 different presentation times in total, and correspondingly had 7 different random orderings of presentation time. For each presentation time and image, we had 20 subjects.

This means that for a single image we have 140 responses across 7 time values.

For each image, we created a set of yes/no questions that covered the full spectrum of subject responses for that image. For example, we created questions like "A person was mentioned" and then scored this as a 1 if a subject's response mentioned a person and a 0 otherwise. As mentioned, we created these questions exhaustively based on the 140 responses for each image.

For each image that means we have a different set of yes/no questions (but these questions are the same across all time conditions). To draw comparisons across different images, we can collapse groups of these yes/no questions to refer to a more general category:

- For example, we might have had "A bag was mentioned" in one image and "A phone was mentioned" in another image, to make a comparison we can use the general question "An object was mentioned".
- We have created some general categories to make these comparisons across all 14 images so you can assume that.

We are interested in doing some statistical analysis on these yes/no questions. Primarily, we are interested in knowing whether there are significant differences across presentation times within an image, but also if there are significant differences across presentation times across images (by performing some aggregations as described above).

We are not statisticians and are looking for some general guidance/how to approach this kind of data.

Any help is much appreciated, thanks.

Comment: This is too abstract. Please tell us what are your stimuli, what are the subjects (persons, animals, ?) what is the time scale, ... and most important, what is your goal. All explained in language that you do understand, do not try to "translate" to statistics for us, we can do that!

Comment: Hi @kjetilbhalvorsen sorry I took a while to get back to this! I have made some edits to try and describe what we have in clearer terms. Please let me know if you have any more questions, and any advice would be much appreciated! Thanks